# Facebook conversion pixel can prevent website load?

Tags: facebook-ads-api

If the Facebook conversion pixel is placed on website A, and if Facebook is blocked (as some orgs do prevent their users from accessing FB), then will that Facebook pixel somehow prevent website A from being loaded correctly for that user?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, it shouldn't. The pixel code makes a request to Facebook's servers when loaded by the user's browser. If the user's network blocks requests to Facebook servers that should only affect that request and nothing else about the website, assuming there are no other blocks on resources for that site (such as other CSS or JS files). I recommend confirming that you're using the right Facebook pixel code which has been designed not to break websites that use it.